# How to display a value in readonly text input using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Below is an example of a table I have displayed in my application:

```
Marks Per Answer               Total Marks    Marks Remaining

(blank text input)              
(blank text input)               6              6           

(blank readonly text input)      4              0
```

The problem I have is that what is supose to happen is that any readonly text inputs in the table should display the same value as the number under "Total Marks" column. So the table should look like this below:

```
Marks Per Answer                   Total Marks    Marks Remaining

(blank text input)                    
(blank text input)                    6              6

(readonly text input value='4')       4              0
```

My question is that what do I need to change in my code below in order to display the correct values in the read only text inputs?

```
if ($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").length == 1) {
    //alert(t_marks);
    var t_marks = $("[class*=q" + i + "_ans]");
    var t_marksHtml = t_marks.html();
    t_marks.html("0");
    $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(t_marksHtml).attr('readonly', true);
    //$("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").attr('readonly',true);
}
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='totalmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="2">6</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q1_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="2"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr class="questiontd">
    <td class="answertd" name="answers[]">D</td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q2_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
</td>
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="1">6</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q2_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="1"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: _"any readonly text inputs in the table should display"_ - But there are no readonly ones in your html, only what you're setting to readonly in your JS - could you explain more about which ones you want to set readonly? Also, your html is invalid: `id` should be unique, so you should be using `id` for the `qx_mark_0` instead of making that a style.

Comment: This: `$('#markstbl input[readonly]').val(function(i, oldVal) {return $(this).closest("tr").find(".totalmarkstd").text(); });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​` will find any fields that are _already_ readonly and set their value to the total marks value from the same table row...

Comment: seems you missleading question: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aAjmW/ no any problem to set text to readonly input

Comment: your selector is terrible, why you need jquery ?

Comment: I have not included whole jquery functionand full html in my code, but what I am trying to do is state that if a question only contains a sigle answer, then the text input for that question should be readonly, else if there are multiple answers in a question, then the text inputs in that question is not readonly

Comment: Do you want me to display the full html and jquery code?

Comment: @nnnnnn are you saying change the current classes I have `class="individualMarks q2_mark_0"` for example to id and change the current id `id="individualtext"`to `class="individualtext"`?

Comment: `id="q2_mark_0" class="individualMarks individualtext"` would make more sense. The `"q2_mark_0"` part uniquely identifies the field and that's what the `id` attribute is for - if more than one field could be a `"q2_mark_0"` field then keep it as a class and don't use `id` at all. You'd make `"individualMarks"` and `"individualtext"` classes because they apply to multiple fields.

Comment: By the way, your table is kind of odd in that the second row has an extra cell sticking out to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/pREJ2/ - is that deliberate?

Comment: @nnnnnn No its because I tried to only include the relevant html code that I must of removed the relevant code incorrectly, the full table looks like this: (http://jsfiddle.net/M9Fhk/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need something like  this, because of ugly markup of table (with span) it is hard to select the proper number of remain marks, so here a bug that allow -1 , all other works fine,

You need to review your markup, because relations between input and remain marks are unclean.

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/M9Fhk/2/)

```
$('.individualMarks').change(function() {
    t = $(this);
    console.log(t.parents('tr').get(0));
    var remain_e = t.parents('tr').children('.noofmarkstd').last().children();
    console.log(remain_e.get(0));
    if (remain_e.length < 1) {
        var c = 2;
        var m = $(this);
        while (remain_e.length < 1 && c < 100) {

            remain_e = m.parents('tr').prev().children('.noofmarkstd').last().children();
            m = m.parents('tr').prev();
            c++;
        }
        if (c >= 100) {
            console.error('error finding element!');
            return;
        }
    }
    remain = remain_e.html();
    remain--;
    if (remain <= 0) {
        t.attr('readonly', "true"), remain_e.parents('tr').find('input').attr('readonly', "true")
    };
    remain_e.html(remain);
});​
```